# Parsing of Windows BSOD minidump file

Tags: windows, debugging, dump

I am trying to write an utility (Python script) which parses the Windows BSOD minidump files. I can not use MS utility WinDbg for this purposes. Everything I find online considers mostly process (user-space) dumps. A couple of links which talk about BSOD dumps are apparently outdated (?). 
For example, my dump file header looks like

```
    1 0000000: 5041 4745 4455 3634 0f00 0000 b01d 0000  PAGEDU64........
    2 0000010: 00d0 6d1e 0000 0000 20b2 9002 00f8 ffff  ..m..... .......
    3 0000020: 500e 8a02 00f8 ffff 302b 8802 00f8 ffff  P.......0+......
    4 0000030: 6486 0000 0100 0000 7f00 0000 5041 4745  d...........PAGE
    5 0000040: 0800 0000 0000 0000 3100 0580 0000 0000  ........1.......
    6 0000050: f806 0400 0000 0000 0b7c 1201 80f8 ffff  .........|......
    7 0000060: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
    8 0000070: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
```

I would expect to find at the offset 0x1db0 (see https://crashpad.chromium.org/doxygen/structMINIDUMP__HEADER.html) an array of directories. Instead I see:

```
   476 0001db0: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
   477 0001dc0: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
   478 0001dd0: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
   479 0001de0: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
   480 0001df0: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
   481 0001e00: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
   482 0001e10: 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745 5041 4745  PAGEPAGEPAGEPAGE
```

There is another link with completely different structure http://computer.forensikblog.de/en/2008/02/64bit-crash-dumps.html . The structure is Ok for a large (full?) dump file, but for not a minidump one I see.

What am I missing?

Update1. Solution with pykd works, but I would really prefer something smaller and platform independent. It appears that BlueScreenView from nirsoft.net does the trick without dependencies on DbgEng.dll. At least I did not see LoadLibrary calls for DbgEng. It means that at least one person has cracked the "not full" BSOD dump. I have made some progress with the dump, but I do not have full picture yet. I can get only list of the loaded modules. Tip - one of the 16 bits offsets in the 0x2000 section points (in my case 0x2034 has value 0xd480) to the table of unicode strings.

Update2.
Something like this probably does the job https://github.com/larytet/parse_minidump/blob/master/parse_minidump.py

I am still missing lot of things. Specifically details how the stack is defined. This is probably good enough for my purposes.

Comment: A kernel crash dump is not a minidump.  Not a lot of opportunity to make it mini when the kernel doesn't work anymore :)

Comment: @HansPassant: at least WinDbg calls them like that sometimes, e.g. "64 bit Kernel Mini Dump Analysis"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pykd](http://pykd.codeplex.com)

Simple script:

```
 import pykd
 pykd.loadDump("dump.dmp")
 print pykd.getStack()
```

Comment: The package depends on WinDbg. The problem is that I do not want/can not distribute WinDbg with my solution

Comment: it is not depend on Windbg. You can install pykd without windbg by pip:  pip install pykd

Comment: On MacOS I am getting

Comment: pip install pykd                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Collecting pykd
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pykd (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pykd

Comment: sorry, pykd works only on Windows :(. Try to look on http://www.volatilityfoundation.org/ As I known, it supports any types of dump and works on any platform

Comment: Works for Windows. Does the pykd wheel contains WinDbg.dll? Because I see in the code things like kdlib/dbgengine.h

Comment: it does not contain exactlty "windbg.dll", but it has copy of the dbgeng.dll ( and some others dlls, like msdia ).

Comment: How can I see the list of loaded kernel drivers? My goal is to map the exception address (the stack frame or address returned by the getLastException) to the actual driver where it happened. Thanks

Comment: try:
print pykd.module( pykd.getLastException().exceptionAddress )

Comment: Thank you!  You are absolutely great.

Comment: I have partially cracked the format. See https://github.com/larytet/parse_minidump/blob/master/parse_minidump.py